# I got RunDLL Error. what is WerConCpl.dll?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I'm fresh man in software engineering and I've been working on an MFC Application on Windows 7.

I have a problem with a DLL. When I run this application, this error sometimes occurs:

> There was a problem starting `C:\Windows\system32\WerConCpl.dll`

What is this DLL and what is this DLL used for?

Any answer or clue will be appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: [What’s the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don’t use it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643).

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your reply. If you don't mind, would you teach me What WerConCpl.dll is used for? I will appreciate it if answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google with that DLL filename leads me to [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e9652c92-ea54-4d4e-8961-453a1c7597c6/werconcpldll-what-is-this?forum=w7itprosecurity). The accepted answer states:

> `werconcpl.dll` will access Internet because *it is looking for solutions to submitted crash reports*.

This file is a Microsoft Windows system file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have one more question. Can I block this pop-up error window by doing something?

Comment: @Jay I don’t know, sorry. Please upvote and accept the answer if you  want to. I feel your second question is a separate issue and might not even be a programming issue. You’ll need to start a new question with enough sample code to reproduce the error. Then someone might be able to suggest an improvement to your code.